# How do I get more stuff from the wishing well?

Tags: candy-box

When I put my candy in and got more lollipops, it will not let me get anything else. How do I do this and get more stuff from it?

Comment: so anyone know?

Comment: You can't. That's the whole point of the well; you can only use it once.

Comment: you forgot to answer it in the answer down below.

Comment: Well, "you can't" isn't a very good answer, and I don't have time to pull up a reference or anything :P you can self-answer your question if you would like.

Comment: I can't I just started this account or i need 10 reputation and i only have 1

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow if no is the only answer, then I guess its the only answer.

Comment: It is possible if you cheat.  Is it permitted to post cheats here?

Comment: It's also possible to get more than one "reward" from the wishing well if you're playing Candy Box **2**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to get more things from the Wishing Well. There are three set defaults:

"Multiply my candies by 5"

"Multiply my lollipops by 8"

"Give me lots of potions and scrolls"

From the [Candy Box Wiki](http://www.candyboxwiki.com/wiki/Wishing_Well):

*Take care ! You can use this bonus only once!
When this is done, the well will advise you
"I will grant you one wish! So choose carefully from the list below".*

I think that pretty much sums it up. You get one wish, the well warns you to choose carefully because you only get one chance. There is no other way around this.